# I want to show sql query for below r code but getting error for slice function

Tags: sql, r

I want to display sql query for below R-code but I'm getting error after running the code.

```
ID <- rep(1, times = 20)
Date <- c("2010-12-09", "2010-12-09", "2010-12-09", "2010-12-09", "2010-12-09", "2010-12-09", "2010-12-09", "2010-12-09", "2010-12-27", "2010-12-27", "2010-12-27", "2010-12-27", "2011-01-14", "2011-01-14", "2011-01-14", "2011-01-14", "2011-01-14", "2011-01-14", "2011-01-14", "2011-01-14")
Agent <- c("Agent1", "Agent2", "Agent3", "Agent4", "Agent1", "Agent2", "Agent3", "Agent4", "Agent1", "Agent2", "Agent3", "Agent4", "Agent1", "Agent2", "Agent3", "Agent4", "Agent1", "Agent2", "Agent3", "Agent4")

df <- data.frame(ID, Date, Agent) 
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr) 
df1=memdb_frame(df)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(group = ceiling(as.integer(difftime(Date, min(Date), units = 'week')/4))) %>% 
    group_by(ID, group, Agent)%>%
    slice(which.min(Date))%>% show_query()

Error in `slice()`:
! `slice()` is not supported on database backends
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I'm happy about any help !

Comment: Use `slice_min()` rather than `slice(which.min())`. As noted on the `?slide` help page "`slice, `slice_head`, and `slice_tail` are not supported since database tables have no intrinsic order." and `dbplyr` can't recognize automatically how to translate that command.

Comment: It's working with slice_min() but I'm getting different output. Can we have any other way to do it.

Comment: You wanted a different output, right? The previous output was an error.